# Printing cyclic data structures

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.7

Python's print statement often works on arbitrary data structures (in particular those made by argparse.Namespace), which is useful. One case where it doesn't work is where you're dealing with complex object graphs containing cycles (one object points to another, which points back to the original object); this trips infinite recursion on trying to convert the objects to a string.

Is there a way to create a string representation, suitable for printing for debugging purposes, that checks for cycles and so can handle arbitrary object graphs? (Python 2.7 if it matters.)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  The way to create a string representation that checks for cycles is to check for cycles in your string representation code.  Look at what Python prints, for instance, when you do `a = [1]` and then `a[0] = a` and print the resulting list.  Exactly how you would handle this depends on how your string representation code works, which you don;t describe in your question.

Comment: @BrenBarn Ah! You're right, the string conversion for lists already correctly handles cycles; it's the string conversion for argparse.Namespace that doesn't. I suppose my question then is whether anyone has already written string conversion code for argparse.Namespace that does handle cycles, to save me reinventing the wheel if so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I wrote my own function for printing an argparse.Namespace object that may directly or indirectly reference a cyclic data structure:

```
def pr(a):
    print 'Namespace'
    seen = set()
    def f(a, indent):
        for k, v in sorted(a.__dict__.items()):
            s = indent * ' '
            if type(v) == argparse.Namespace:
                if id(v) in seen:
                    print '%s%s: Namespace' % (s, k)
                else:
                    seen.add(id(v))
                    print '%s%s:' % (s, k)
                    f(v, indent + 1)
            elif type(v) == bytearray:
                print '%s%s: bytearray(%s)' % (s, k, len(v))
            elif type(v) == list:
                print '%s%s: [%s]' % (s, k, len(v))
            elif type(v) == str:
                print '%s%s: %s' % (s, k, repr(v))
            elif type(v) == tuple:
                print '%s%s: (%s)' % (s, k, len(v))
            elif type(v) in (int, long):
                print '%s%s: %x' % (s, k, v)
            else:
                print '%s%s: %s' % (s, k, v)
    f(a, 1)
```